# How to iterate through three lists in parallel in Yaml file

Tags: yaml, jinja2

Need 3 variables to change on every iteration.

```
ver = [1,2,3]
tes = [a,b,c]
bet = [1a.2b.3c]

{% for v,t,b in ver,tes,bet %}
 {{ v }} {{ t }} {{ b}}
{% endfor %}
```

o/p:

```
1 a 1a
2 b 2b
3 c 3c
```

I ran the same, got a very messy o/p. There should be only 3 iterations printing 3 variables in each iteration.
How can i perform the above operations using the `for` loop ? In the above case

Any suggestions on where I'm going wrong, would help Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following code:

```
{% for i in range([ver|count, tes|count, bet|count]|min) %}
  {{ ver[i] }} {{ tes[i] }} {{ bet[i] }}
{% endfor %}
```

It uses only built in filters and functions:

- count
- min (to handle sequences with different length, similarly as zip in python)
- range

Entire code in python:

```
import jinja2

ver = [1, 2, 3, 4]
tes = ['a', 'b', 'c']
bet = ['1a', '2b', '3c']
t = jinja2.Template('''{% for i in range([ver|count, tes|count, bet|count]|min) %}
  {{ ver[i] }} {{ tes[i] }} {{ bet[i] }}
{% endfor %}
''')
print(t.render(ver=ver, tes=tes, bet=bet))
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you need something that behaves like Python's `zip` function. Here's one option, in which we simply expose `zip` to the Jinja environment:

```
>>> import jinja2
>>> ver=[1,2,3]
>>> tes=['a','b','c']
>>> bet=['1a','2b','3c']
>>> t=jinja2.Template('''{% for v,t,b in zip(ver,tes,bet) %}
...  {{ v }} {{ t }} {{ b}}
... {% endfor %}
... ''')
>>> t.environment.globals.update(zip=zip)
>>> print(t.render(ver=ver,tes=tes,bet=bet))

 1 2 3

 a b c

 1a 2b 3c

>>>
```

Comment: Thanks for your time,  Yes you right similar to zip functionality in python but in a yaml file ! Not using python in my case

Comment: You forgot to use zip in the template

Comment: @Lesiak whoops, yes, copy and pasted from the wrong thing :). I've updated the answer.